# Fazer o botão aparecer ao fim do video

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, html5-video

Estou fazendo um projeto EAD, gostaria de fazer um script que realizasse a seguinte função:

Ao assistir um video até o final(ou 80/90%) apareça o botão de avançar aula.

```js
<script>
var btn = document.querySelector("#validaaula");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    var div = document.querySelector("#Videoaula");
    
  if(div.style.display === "none") {
        div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
  }
    
});
</script>
```

```html
<button id="validaaula">Ação</button>

<iframe width="30%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7lrot9ONZ8E" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen id="Videoaula"></iframe>
```

Atualmente o script está assim, não avancei por que não sei como identificar o fim do vídeo para fazer a ação de trocar o display none para block do botão.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso com JS puro, vai ter que criar o player pelo próprio script usando a API do youtube. Fiz um exemplo de código com a função que você falou:

```html
<body>
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>
    <button id="validaaula">Ação</button>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
    <script>
        let video = document.querySelector('#ytplayer')
        let btn = document.querySelector('#validaaula')
        let player

        // Criação do player
        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            events: {
                'onReady': videoVerify,
                'onStateChange': videoVerify
        }
        });
        }
        
        // Toda vez que o video está pronto ou muda de estado, esta função é invocada.
        function videoVerify() {
        if (player.getCurrentTime() < .9 * player.getDuration()) {
            btn.style.display= 'none'
        } else {
            btn.style.display= 'block'
        }
        }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Site com informações sobre a API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Video_Queueing_Functions

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, entendi meu erro

Answer (score -2):

Olá. Você pode usar o seguinte:

Defina os segundo que devesse aparecer através de segundos

```js
        const videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");

        videoPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (event) {
            if (videoPlayer.currentTime >= 5) { //defina traves de segundos. Ex: 120s = 2 minutos
                document.querySelector('.pular').style.display = "block";
            }else{
                document.querySelector('.pular').style.display = "none";
            }
        });
```

```css
.pular{
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="videoPlayer" autoplay controls src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    <button class="pular">Próximo episódio</button>
</body>
</html>
```